# Error: unable to locate package libpam-google-authenticator

Tags: apt, pam, ubuntu-18.04

I'm having trouble setting up 2 factor authentication in Ubuntu Server 18.04.

I'm following this tutorial: http://www.ubuntuboss.com/how-to-set-up-2-factor-authentication-in-ubuntu-server-18-04/

But on the first step when I try to install the package I get the package not found error as seen in the title.

`sudo apt-get install libpam-google-authenticator`

I have looked around to see if the package has been updated and goes by a different name and I am sure I have the most recent version of the package manager.

Has the package changed or is there anyway  around this problem.

Comment: The error means that the package is not in one of your repositories. Are you sure you have the right repository installed?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Turned out it's because Ubuntu Server doesn't include the Universe Repository.

Add this line
`sudo add-apt-repository universe`

Then run the command again and it will install.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way round this issue,

```
/tmp$ wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/326531917/libpam-google-authenticator_20170702-1_amd64.deb
```

I was able to manually install it via this link and installed the missing dependencies the same way and was able to finish the tutorial as normal.